# Join & Group By - Column is invalid in the select list

Tags: sql, group-by

I'm running a query to join 2 tables and then group the rows by 2 fields and select the rows with the min ID from these groups and I get an error. The joined table looks like:

```
+--------+---------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+
|   ID   |  CODE   |      NAME       | VRACHAR01 | VRACHAR02 |
+--------+---------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+
| 290861 | 1110896 | PRODUCT NAME XX |       001 |       706 |
| 290864 | 1110899 | PRODUCT NAME XX |       001 |       706 |
| 290865 | 1110900 | PRODUCT NAME XX |       003 |       721 |
| 290870 | 1110905 | PRODUCT NAME XX |       004 |       743 |
| 290871 | 1110906 | PRODUCT NAME XX |       004 |       743 |
| 290878 | 1110913 | PRODUCT NAME XX |       006 |       806 |
| 290879 | 1110914 | PRODUCT NAME XX |       007 |       807 |
| 290908 | 1110943 | PRODUCT NAME XX |       008 |       815 |
+--------+---------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+
```

If I run the script below to group the results by the last 2 fields I get an error:

> Column 'A.CODE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
    SELECT
        min(A.ID),
        A.CODE, 
        A.NAME, 
        B.VARCHAR01, 
        B.VARCHAR02
    FROM
        PRODUCTS A
    INNER JOIN
        EXTRAS B 
      ON 
        A.ID = B.ID
    WHERE
        A.COMPANY = 1002
    AND
        A.TYPE = 50
    GROUP BY
        B.VARCHAR01,
        B.VARCHAR02
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: (1) The error seems pretty clear; the `group by` columns are not consistent with the `select` columns.  What do you not understand? (2) What do you want to accomplish?  That is not clear.  (3) What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the min id, then you don't need other columns:

```
SELECT MIN(P.ID), E.VARCHAR01, E.VARCHAR02
FROM PRODUCTS P INNER JOIN
     EXTRAS E
     ON P.ID = E.ID
WHERE P.COMPANY = 1002 AND P.TYPE = 50
GROUP BY E.VARCHAR01, E.VARCHAR02;
```

Note that this replaces the meaningless table aliases with abbreviations for the table names.

If you want the entire row, then you can use window functions:

```
SELECT PE.*
FROM (SELECT P.*, E.VARCHAR01, E.VARCHAR02,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY E.VARCHAR01, E.VARCHAR02 ORDER BY P.ID ASC) as seqnum
      FROM PRODUCTS P INNER JOIN
           EXTRAS E
           ON P.ID = E.ID
      WHERE P.COMPANY = 1002 AND P.TYPE = 50
     ) PE
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, the first solution is what I was looking for.